# Segmentation fault when run hello.s by GNU Assembler in Cygwin

Tags: assembly, cygwin, gnu, windows-7-x64

I use gcc in Cygwin (in Windows7-64 bit) to run this example
http://asm.sourceforge.net/howto/build.html

```
.data                   # section declaration
msg:
    .ascii  "Hello, world!\n"   # our dear string
    len = .-msg         # length of our dear string
.text                   # section declaration
            # we must export the entry point to the ELF linker or
    .global _start  # loader. They conventionally recognize _start as their
            # entry point. Use ld -e foo to override the default.
_start:
# write our string to stdout
    movl    $len,%edx   # third argument: message length
    movl    $msg,%ecx   # second argument: pointer to message to write
    movl    $1,%ebx     # first argument: file handle (stdout)
    movl    $4,%eax     # system call number (sys_write)
    int $0x80       # call kernel
# and exit
    movl    $0,%ebx     # first argument: exit code
    movl    $1,%eax     # system call number (sys_exit)
    int $0x80       # call kernel
```

by command line in Cygwin
    **$as -o hello.o hello.s && ld -s -o hello hello.o && ./hello**
the result is
    **Segmentation fault**

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

Cygwin doens't make Windows binary-compatible with Linux, so Linux system calls using int $0x80 will fail as Windows has a completely different convention for system calls. The generated binaries should work fine in an actual (or compatible) Linux environment, though.

Comment: I compiler in Cygwin and run it in Cygwin

Comment: Doesn't matter. int $0x80 doesn't work on Windows, even with Cygwin.

Comment: **"Windows has a completely different convention for system calls"**. Doesn't Windows not allow you to use system calls at all?

Comment: Well, Windows certainly does have system calls, as does pretty much every OS in existence. But I assume you're referring to the fact that even if you were to use Windows' system call conventions here it wouldn't work, since Windows provides a completely different, incompatible set of system calls.