# linker outputs 'relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32' when trying to link yasm assembled program

Tags: assembly, cygwin, ld

I have a simple asm file:

```
$ cat my.asm
    segment .text
    global _start

_start:
        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,5
        int 0x80
```

Assembling with yasm works ok:

```
$ yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2  -l my.lst my.asm
```

Linking returns some output:

```
$ ld -o my my.o
my.o:(.debug_aranges+0x6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.debug_info'
my.o:(.debug_info+0x6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.debug_abbrev'
my.o:(.debug_info+0xc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.debug_line'
```

However, no executable is created.

My environment is:

```
$ yasm --version
yasm 1.2.0

$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.23.52.20130604

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 MYHOST 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:37 x86_64 Cygwin
```

The code snippet and assembling/linking steps came from the book: [Introduction to 64bit Intel Assembly Language Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Intel-Assembly-Language-Programming/dp/1466470038)

Any pointers as to why this is not working will be appreciated.

Comment: Might be relevant, even though it's not the *exact* same situation: http://www.technovelty.org/c/relocation-truncated-to-fit-wtf.html Also look at the `-a` and `-m` options to `yasm`. `-f` only sets the object format, you will probably have to tell `yasm` to make the code 64-bit, too.

Comment: I notice that the errors seem to be in the .debug section. What happens if you assemble it without the `-g` switch?

Comment: Linking works ok if I drop the `-g` switch.  However, running the binary gives segmentation fault.  This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132781/segmentation-fault-when-run-hello-s-by-gnu-assembler-in-cygwin) suggests that cygwin has issues with linux type calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin binaries that use Linux system calls cannot run on windows - even through cygwin. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132896/1033422) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely writing 32-bit code ("int 0x80") but compile/assemble as 64-bit code ("-f elf64").

You must assemble the code as 32-bit code.

Comment: The code and assembly/linking steps came from the book [Introduction to 64bit Intel Assembly Language Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Intel-Assembly-Language-Programming/dp/1466470038) :(